# Вывести список рабочих групп Windows

Tags: windows, консоль

В консоли *Windows* надо вывести список сетевых рабочих групп.

Какими командами можно воспользоваться, чтобы сделать это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Я так понял нужен список групп из домена.

   ```
   net localgroup /domain

   net group /domain
   ```
2. Там, где есть утилита dsquery:

   ```
   dsquery group -desc *
   ```
3. Также можно попробовать использовать WMI запросы используя утилиту
   wmic.

   ```
   wmic path Win32_Group get Name
   ```

Недостаток этой команды в том, что в начале она выводит список локальных групп компьютера. Значит запрос нужно фильтровать. Впрочем, это решаемо. Как для предыдущей команды, так и для текущей.

Comment: Спасибо! Помог!